# Tasker Newbie Question

Tags: tasker

I am learning tasker and reading up tutorial on http://tasker.dinglisch.net/tour.html.

If you look at the picture,
you can see the two same tasks "Set Widget Icon".
Is that a typo, or something I do not understand?

[image]

Also, what is the benefit of toggle? Why is the property ternary, not just off and on? Can you please help with a practical example?

Thanks much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that seems to be a typo: the conditions should be `If %WIFI ~ on` and `If %WIFI !~ on` (or `If %WIFI ~ off`).

The [%WIFI variable](http://tasker.dinglisch.net/userguide/en/variables.html) can only be `on` or `off`, not `toggle`. But the Wifi action can be used to enable, disable or toggle Wifi, i.e. if Wifi is enabled, it will be disabled, and if Wifi is disabled, it will be enabled.

The example (minus the typo) talks about creating a "Toggle Wifi" widget: if Wifi is on and you click the icon, Wifi will be disabled and the icon will be changed to a "Wifi is off" icon. And if Wifi is off and you click the icon, Wifi will be enabled and the icon will be changed to a "Wifi is on" icon.